# jQuery slider - prev and next issue

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to make a simple slider with prev and next buttons.
If go a step forward and than backward i don't get always the previous image .
I have noticed that the next and prev button don't use the same index but I don't know how to  fix that.

```
   $("img").hide();
    $("img").first().show();

    var currentItem = $("img").first().next().index();
    var lastItem = $("img").last().index();


    $('#next').click(function(){
        $("img").hide();
        $("img").eq(currentItem).show();
        if(currentItem == lastItem){
            currentItem = 0;
        }else{
            currentItem = $("img").eq(currentItem).next().index();
        }
    });


   var currentItem2 = $("img").last().prev().index();

    $('#prev').click(function(){
        $("img").hide();
        $("img").eq(currentItem2).show();
        if( currentItem2 == lastItem ){
            currentItem2 = 2;
        }else{
            currentItem2 = $("img").eq(currentItem2).prev().index();

        }
    });
```

This is my html code

```
 <div id="slider">

    <img src="bilder/walle.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="bilder/up.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="bilder/toystory.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="bilder/nemo.jpg"alt=""/>

    <div id="next">Next</div>
    <div id="prev">prev</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my other answer.. it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117752/side-scrolling-inside-html-widget/22117788#22117788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var images = [];
$('#slider img').each(function(){
    images.push($(this));    
});
var imgcount = images.length;
$("img").hide();
$("img").first().show();
var currentItem = 0;

$('#next').click(function(){
        $("img").hide();
        currentItem++;
        images[currentItem%4].show();        
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
        $("img").hide();
       currentItem--;
       if(currentItem < 0)
           currentItem = imgcount-1;
       images[currentItem%4].show();
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wmxzK/

Comment: @user3371372 Your welcome, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the little white checkmark to the left of my answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just by modifying a bit Trevor's code, you could have something like that:

```
var images = [];
$('#slider img').each(function () {
    images.push($(this));
    $(this).hide();
});

var imgcount = images.length;
var currentItem = 0;
images[currentItem].show();

$('#next').click(function () {
    images[currentItem].hide();
    currentItem = (currentItem + 1) % imgcount;
    images[currentItem].show();
});

$('#prev').click(function () {
    images[currentItem].hide();
    if (currentItem > 0)
        currentItem--;
    else
        currentItem = imgcount - 1;
    images[currentItem].show();
});
```

Then your code still works if you want to add new images, and you will not hide all the images of your web page each time you click next or previous :)

http://jsfiddle.net/wmxzK/4/

Comment: I'm trying to understand JQuery better, and I was surprised to find that wrapping the images in anchor tags your example still works. But it looks like the code is just cycling through the images, why / how does it also cycle the links around each image?